# How do I fix missing values in a for-loop in a Python list?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, keras, bioinformatics

I want to encode the value of a Python list to refine it, but the value is missing in the middle of my function.

My environments are as follows.

PC 1 - Windows 10 (64-bit) without GPU, Python 3.6.8 (Anaconda), PyCharm 2018.1.

PC 2 - Windows 10 (64-bit) with GPU, Python 3.6.8 (Anaconda), PyCharm 2019.1.

I want to get protein sequence information from 'enzyme.txt' file and convert the string data to integer type. However, since the sequence is a string, I made a function to create and convert a dictionary table like code when changing to an integer. However, I do not know what the reason is, but there is no value when i = 860, j = 106 in x [i] [j] So, the for-loop stopped with the error attached below.

```py
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import np_utils


file = 'enzyme.txt'


def data(file):
    f = open(file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    seq = []
    ec = []
    for i in range(0, len(lines)):
        lines[i] = lines[i].strip('\n')
        seq.append(lines[i][:-2])
        ec.append(lines[i][-1])
    f.close()
    return seq, ec

x, y = data(file)

Amino_Acid_Scalar = {
    'X': 0,
    'A': 1,
    'C': 2,
    'D': 3,
    'E': 4,
    'F': 5,
    'G': 6,
    'H': 7,
    'I': 8,
    'K': 9,
    'L': 10,
    'M': 11,
    'N': 12,
    'P': 13,
    'Q': 14,
    'R': 15,
    'S': 16,
    'T': 17,
    'V': 18,
    'W': 19,
    'Y': 20
}


def amino_acid_to_scalar(amino_acid):
    if not amino_acid in Amino_Acid_Scalar:
        return None
    return Amino_Acid_Scalar[amino_acid]


def sequence_to_scalar(sequence):
    scalar = [amino_acid_to_scalar(amino_acid) for amino_acid in sequence]
    if None in scalar:
        return None
    return scalar


def sequences_to_scalar(sequences):
    scalars = [sequence_to_scalar(sequence) for sequence in sequences]
    return scalars


x = sequences_to_scalar(x)

for i in range(0, len(x)):
    for j in range(0, len(x[i])):
        #print(x[i][j], i, j)
        #tmp = x[i][j]
        #print(tmp)
        #arr[i][j] = tmp
        pass

y = np_utils.to_categorical(y, 7)
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y, dtype='int64')
```

In the 'enzyme.txt' file, columns 858 through 862 are as follows.

```
ATKAVCVLKGDGPVQGIINFEQKESNGPVKVWGSIKGLTEGLHGFHVHEFGDNTAGCTSAGPHFNPLSRKHGGPKDEERHVGDLRNVTADKDGVADVSIEDSVISLSGDHCIIGRTLVVHEKADDLGKGGNEESTKTGNAGSRLACGVIGIAQ,1
ATKAVCVLKGDGPVQGIINFEQKESNGPVKVWGSIKGLTEGLHGFHVHEFGDNTAGCTSAGPHFNPLSRKHGGPKDEERHVGDLRNVTADKDGVADVSIEDSVISLSGDHCIIGRTLVVHEKADDLGKGGNEESTKTGNAGSRLACGVIGIAQ,1
MRVVVIGAGVIGLSTALCIHERYHSVLQPLDIKVYADRFTPLTTTDVAAGLWQPYLSDPNNPQEADWSQQTFDYLLSHVHGCALEAAKLFGRILEEKKLSRMPPSHL,1
MPKFYCDYCDTYLTHDSPSVRKTHCSGRKHKENVKDYYCKWMEEQAQSLIDKTTAAFQQGKIPPTPFSAPPPAGAMIUGGGAAACUCGACUGCAUAAUUUGUGGUAGUGGGGGACUGCGUUCGCGCUUUCCCCUG,1
GPHMSIHSGRIAAVHNVPLSVLIRPLPSVLDPAKVQSLVDTIREDPDSVPPIDVLWIKGAQGGDYFYSFGGSHRYAAYQQLQRETIPAKLVQSTLSDLRVYLGASTPDLQ,1
```

The following error is displayed.

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1\helpers\pydev\pydev_run_in_console.py", line 53, in run_file
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Inyong/Documents/PycharmProjects/Test/Test_4_TXT.py", line 81, in <module>
    for j in range(0, len(x[i])):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

So when I try to see the value of where it stopped,

```
> x[860][106]
```

I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tracked down the problem well.  What you are seeing there is `x = None`
or `x[860]=None` because you can't have `None[186]`.

My suggestions about the code as a whole:

- first get out of the habit of iteration over `len(thing)` or `range(len(thing))`.  Because errors are hard to track down aren't they :).  See a wonderful talk on the subject https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnSu9hHGq5o
- opening files is easier using the keyword "with" you will see it in documentation as a context manager (see below for an example on how to use it)
- Down at the bottom you have numpy code.  While I think it's great you are contemplating speed.  I would avoid doing either Numpy or Pandas .astype('category')
  or something like it because one sequence might be all "L"'s at which point they would all map to zero instead of ten like you have in the Amino_Acid_Scalar dictionary.
- I don't know if the Amino_Acid_Scalar values were something you picked or were given to you but I would suggest using something simpler like `ord(base)-65` then your mapping will be easier and
- your bases will fit nicely into a Numpy Array with int8 as the dtype.

This code can be shortened.

```
def amino_acid_to_scalar(amino_acid):
    if not amino_acid in Amino_Acid_Scalar:
        return None
    return Amino_Acid_Scalar[amino_acid]
```

You can replace this function with the dictionary "get" method:

```
Amino_Acid_Scalar.get(amino_acid, None)
```

where "None" is the default value you want sent back if there is no key.  (or you can use the shortend version `Amino_Acid_scalar.get(amino_acid)` because None is the default return value)

```
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import np_utils


Amino_Acid_Scalar = {
    'X': 0,
    'A': 1,
    'C': 2,
    'D': 3,
    'E': 4,
    'F': 5,
    'G': 6,
    'H': 7,
    'I': 8,
    'K': 9,
    'L': 10,
    'M': 11,
    'N': 12,
    'P': 13,
    'Q': 14,
    'R': 15,
    'S': 16,
    'T': 17,
    'V': 18,
    'W': 19,
    'Y': 20
}

file = 'enzyme.txt'

seqs = []
ecs = []


with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            seq, ec=line.strip().partition(',')[0:3:2]
            seqs.append(seq)
            ecs.append(ec)
        except (ValueError, IndexError) as e:
            print(f'problem was at line {line} with error: {e}')


def sequence_to_scalar(sequence):
    for amino_acid in sequence:
        value = Amino_Acid_Scalar.get(amino_acid, None)
        if value:
            yield value


def sequences_to_scalar(sequences):
    scalars = [sequence_to_scalar(sequence) for sequence in sequences]
    return scalars


scalar_seqs = sequences_to_scalar(seqs)

for count, seq in enumerate(scalar_seqs):
    for count_inner, base in enumerate(seq):
        print(f'{count}, {count_inner}, {base}')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Using the modified code, ```Seq, ec = line.strip (). Partition (',') on line``` ```TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple``` error occurred. So I modified the line as follows, but it works. ```line = line.strip ('\ n'); seq = line [: - 2]; ec = line [-1]; seqs.append (seq); ecs.append (ec)```.  What do you think of my modified code?

Comment: And I tested it by putting `print (count, seq, count_inner, base)` in the bottom of the double for-loop.

In this case, I confirmed that all four variables are output. After output is finished, the following error appears.
 
`for count_inner, base in enumerate (seq): TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

  If I try to define a `dtype` in the usual way I know about `NoneType` to solve this error, an error like `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

I would like to ask if there is any other way.

Comment: My answer is updated:  The reason I wouldn't use ec = line[-1] what happens when you get a 2+ digit number in that field.  (or a negative). Use the power of a Comma.  it's what it's there for.  for the 2nd question: You wanted None's as part of your sequences but now you have to deal with them.  How about filter them out?  (see updated code for a generator using yield)

Comment: I checked the code you updated: `[0: 3: 2]`. The code works fine. I really appreciate it.